# Unbiased estimators of skewness and kurtosis

Tags: probability, statistics

The skewness and kurtosis are defined as:
$$\zeta_3 = \frac{E[(X-\mu)^3]}{E[(X-\mu)^2]^{3/2}} = \frac{\mu_3}{\sigma^3}$$
$$\zeta_4 = \frac{E[(X-\mu)^4]}{E[(X-\mu)^2]^2} = \frac{\mu_4}{\sigma^4}$$

The following formulae are used to calculate sample skewness and kurtosis:
$$z_3 = \frac{\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n} [(x_i-\bar x)^3]}{(\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}[(x_i-\bar x)^2])^{3/2}}$$
$$z_4 = \frac{\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n} [(x_i-\bar x)^4]}{(\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}[(x_i-\bar x)^2])^2}$$

My question is: are these estimators unbiased? I don't know whether I should use unbiased standard deviation or the biased one in the denominator.

In general, if we have a function $f$ whose variables are unbiased estimators, then can we say $f$ is an unbiased estimator as well?

Comment: The link https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skewness#Sample_skewness might be useful.

Comment: Thanks!  I found a relevant paper in the reference. but it seems like there is no unbiased estimator of skewness.

Comment: Is this a general question, or is there a practical application in the background? Skewness can be very misleading in applications. Kurtosis seldom useful. BTW: sample SD $S$ is not unbiased for $\sigma,$ but $S^2$ is unbiased for $\sigma^2.$

Comment: Thanks a lot for the last sentence, I've been always misconceived the biasedness of $S$ and $S^2$. I'm trying to mimic the techniques applied in this paper "Dan Xu, Christian Beck - Transition from lognormal to chi-square superstatistics for financial time series"[http://arxiv.org/abs/1506.01660], but to a different stock. The authors use biased estimators of variance and kurtosis and I doubt that their biasedness may cause some potential or serious problems for the final results.

Comment: They are not unbiased in general: nonlinear functions do not preserve unbiasedness. Moreover, it is possible to construct a family of distributions, for which there is no unbiased estimators for skewness and kurtosis at all.